# HsOpenSSL cipher result different from M2Crypto and command line?

Tags: haskell, openssl, evp-cipher

I'm writing a program to interface with another program written in python. I find that the ciphered results are different.

In ghci, with HsOpenSSL, the ciphered result is `\GS\n\197:`

```
import OpenSSL
import OpenSSL.EVP.Cipher 
import Data.Maybe
method <- fmap fromJust $ withOpenSSL $ getCipherByName "bf-cfb"
cipher method "\x90\x01\x50\x98\x3c\xd2\x4f\xb0\xd6\x96\x3f\x7d\x28\xe1\x7f\x72" "\xcc\x88\xa5\x26\x85\xaf\x7f\x8d" Encrypt "abcd"
```

In python, the ciphered result is `K\x10<Q`

```
import M2Crypto
M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher("bf_cfb", "\x90\x01\x50\x98\x3c\xd2\x4f\xb0\xd6\x96\x3f\x7d\x28\xe1\x7f\x72", "\xcc\x88\xa5\x26\x85\xaf\x7f\x8d", 1).update("abcd")
```

In shell, with *abcd.txt* containing the string "abcd", *abcd.bin* shown in vim as `K^P<Q}`

```
openssl bf-cfb -in abcd.txt -out abcd.bin -pass pass:abc -K 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72 -iv cc88a52685af7f8d -nosalt
```

I assume the M2Crypto result is equivalent to command line result, why the HsOpenSSL result is different?

Comment: I believe M2Crypto uses an 8-bit feedback size; while OpenSSL uses an 64-bit feedback for Blowfish. I've encountered similar issues with mcrypt and Crypto++. There *could* be a problem with padding too. But check feedback size first.

Comment: HsOpenSSL is a wrapper of OpenSSL, it should end up with the same function call. I made a gist to demonstrate the problem: https://gist.github.com/rnons/3d952c60549f9424feb2